# How to select from a selection?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a commenting system, which will have 2 top comments.

How can I select the latest 20 rows, and then from that selection, select the top 2 rows (likes-dislikes)? I can do it with a PHP loop, but it would not be as efficient. Currently I am just selecting the top 2 from the all the comments, but the two top comments never change, since people just up-vote those ones:

```
SELECT * FROM pagecomments WHERE page_id='$pageid' ORDER BY likes-dislikes DESC LIMIT 2
```

EDIT: The table is ordered by the the column "id", which is auto_increment. page_id is the page on the site. Sorry.

Comment: What columns are in your pagecomments table?  Do you have an auto_increment field or a timestamp to decide the latest 20 rows?

Comment: it is difficult to understand what you are trying to do - show us a table and clarify your statement

Comment: The table is ordered by the the column "id", which is auto_increment. page_id is the page on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest your query:

```
SELECT   *
FROM (
  SELECT   *
  FROM     pagecomments
  WHERE    page_id='$pageid'
  ORDER BY date DESC
  LIMIT    20
) t
ORDER BY likes-dislikes DESC
LIMIT    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Order not only by LIkes,  first order by date entered or timestamp.  By ordering by date,  you assure that you`ll get the latest 20 posts or comments.

```
SELECT * FROM pagecomments WHERE page_id='$pageid' ORDER by date_entered desc , 
likes-dislikes DESC limit 2
```

Comment: This would only select the latest 2 comments, regardless of their likes/dislikes.

Comment: After selecting the 20 latest entered row, the query is ordering by likes-dislikes,  indeed there are two ordering conditions,  first by date and then by like-dislike.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `id` column is set to `auto_increment`, use it in a subquery:

```
select *, likes-dislikes
from (
  select *
  from pagecomments
  where page_id='$pageid'
  order by id desc
  limit 20
  ) t
order by likes-dislikes desc
limit 2
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a494b/2)